# Displaying a piece of Union statement side by side

Tags: php, css, mysql

So I have the following Select Statement:

```
SELECT game_name, status, OS 
FROM mobile_version_sports 
UNION ALL 
SELECT game_name, status, OS 
FROM android_sports
```

With that I get the following output:

```
Dragons APPROVED    IOS
Dragons APPROVED    ANDROID
```

With that I have a PHP page that displays everything and uses a small amount of CSS simply to change color of the tabs. In that PHP i have the following code:

```
 foreach($q as $row2){
    print "<tr><td>".$row2['game_name']."</td>";
    print "<td class=".$row2['mobile_version_sports.status'].">".$row2['OS.mobile_version_sports']." 
 </td>";
    print "<td class=".$row2['status.android_sports'].">".$row2['OS.android_sports']."</td></tr>";
}
```

I am having trouble because I would like it to say the name of the Game with the two OS each other with which the will then change based upon the status and my CSS. EDIT: I need this to look this way through PHP to be viewed in the webpage not the SQL call
For example:

```
Dragons IOS ANDROID
```

Comment: Is there a key on the tables that indicates they are the same game, or are the game names just all unique?

Comment: The game name would be the thing that links them. It is not a key but they are mirror copies as far as name

Comment: What type of values does `OS` hold in the `mobile_version_sports` table? This separated table structure seems strange.

Comment: That only holds text of IOS

Comment: Are you in control of this database? Any reason for not putting the 2 tables together? Seems like it would simplify this problem for you greatly.

Comment: Yes, There's a lot of other values in the tables that are updated through scripts. I was handed the database structure and had been told don't adjust it as it would cause more problems in the script

Comment: Would you be ok with just changing your query then? Do you need the `status`?

Comment: Well here's the thing I need everything in the query. I am willing to change how its done. Originally I did a nested loop but noticed today it didn't work that way

Comment: It's also worth noting that table names do not get added to the associative arrays in PHP. (Especially since you're doing a `UNION` query where there is no way to tell the two tables apart.)

Comment: @miken32 How would I do this? That may be the solution

Comment: It's not a solution, it's a comment on the code you posted in your question. `$row2['mobile_version_sports.status']` is not something you would get from any database fetch operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get this by using `JOIN` to get what you need.

```sql
SELECT mobile_version_sports.game_name,
       mobile_version_sports.status AS mobile_version_sports_status,
       mobile_version_sports.OS AS mobile_version_sports_OS,
       android_sports.status AS android_sports_status,
       android_sports.OS AS android_sports_OS
FROM mobile_version_sports
     JOIN android_sports
        ON mobile_version_sports.game_name = android_sports.game_name
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31be6/1

Based on your edit, your PHP code would be like this:

```php
foreach($q as $row2){
    print "<tr><td>".$row2['game_name']."</td>";
    print "<td class=".$row2['mobile_version_sports_status'].">".$row2['mobile_version_sports_OS']." 
 </td>";
    print "<td class=".$row2['android_sports_status'].">".$row2['android_sports_OS']."</td></tr>";
}
```

This will hopefully get you in the right direction.

Comment: When I attempt to run that I get the following:  Result: near "SEPARATOR": syntax error
At line 1:
SELECT game_name, GROUP_CONCAT(OS SEPARATOR

Comment: Make sure your query says this - GROUP_CONCAT(OS SEPARATOR' ') as OS

Comment: I copied it directly from what you had said

Comment: There must be something wrong with your syntax. Post the full code. https://pastebin.com/

Comment: I am pasting what you had said directly into DB browser for sqlite in order to test it quick

Comment: Please post exactly what you have. If I can't see what you have then I can't help  you. If it says you have a syntax error then you have a syntax error. This is working on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d35e6e/16

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203129/discussion-between-alex-oulapour-and-pittsie).

Comment: @Pittsie sqlite <> mysql

Comment: @Pittsie Your post is tagged as MySQL but your comment says you're using SQLite. Which one is your database in question?

Comment: This removes the status which was mentioned as being needed in the result.

Comment: @abney317Updated with status. It was just adding it to the SELECT.

Comment: The statuses might be different on the different tables so that won't work.

Comment: @abney317 Updated with WHERE clauses to filter the proper statuses

Comment: Then your filtering out games that do exist but don't have an approved status in the same way they you'd be filtering out games that don't exist at all.

Comment: Without more information, that's really the best we can assume. If there are more status than 'APPROVED' then those would have to be added to the WHERE. Based on the information in the question though there is no way to know that. This should be a good starting point for OP. However it seems OP may be using SQLLite and not MySQL =(

Comment: @Pittsie I made an update to my answer based on your edit to your question. Hopefully this gets you closer.

Comment: Your current edit requires the game to exist on both tables.

Comment: Right. See the last phrase of the answer. This will hopefully get OP in the right direction. I’m not too sure of all the data requirements needed.

Comment: outer join doesn't exist on mysql or sqllite.. hence my answer

Comment: Oh shoot. I forgot about that. I'll remove that part.

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions here as indicated by your comments:

- `game_name` can be used as a key to link the 2 tables
- `mobile_version_sports` only holds iOS games
- `android_sports` only holds Android games

So with those assumptions, you'll probably have better luck using a query like this that does something similar to a full outer join:

```
SELECT i.game_name, i.status AS iOSStatus, a.status AS androidStatus, 
  i.OS IS NOT NULL AS iOS,
  a.OS IS NOT NULL AS android
FROM mobile_version_sports i
  LEFT JOIN android_sports a ON a.game_name = i.game_name
UNION
SELECT a.game_name, i.status AS iOSStatus, a.status AS androidStatus,
  i.OS IS NOT NULL AS iOS,
  a.OS IS NOT NULL AS android
FROM mobile_version_sports i
  RIGHT JOIN android_sports a ON a.game_name = i.game_name
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c95bd/1)

---

**PHP Code Example:**

```
foreach($q as $row2){
  print "<tr><td>".$row2['game_name']."</td>";

  print "<td>";
  print $row2['iOS'] ? '<span class="' . $row2['iOSStatus'] . '">iOS</span>' : '';
  print $row2['android'] ? '<span class="' . $row2['androidStatus'] . '">Android</span>' : '';
  print "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: If someone is voting this answer down then say why.

Comment: Doing it this way doesn't make it easily extendable if more OS are added or needed. If more OS are added it adds two colums and two places to update each time.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. However I more need the desired result in the PHP code as it uses the CSS to color each box based on Status

Comment: @Alex assumptions made off of what OP told us in the comments and question so it doesn't need to be extendable.

Comment: @Pittsie it should be relatively straightforward with the given query. I can give you an example though but you'll probably have to do some work other than just copying and pasting

Comment: @abney317 That's completely fine I have to do some work no matter what

Answer (score 0):

Try something with this short and simple code, if there is always a match for game_name between the 2 tables. Otherwise use left join with some  `ifnull(a.status,'NOT') as a_status` statments :

```
   SELECT m.game_name,       
          m.OS AS m_OS,
          m.status AS m_status,
          a.OS AS a_OS,
          a.status AS a_status
    FROM mobile_version_sports as m
         JOIN android_sports as a
            ON m.game_name = a.game_name group by m.game_name;
```